# VBA Excel: Sorting by Searching another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to sort information in one sheet in an Excel document by information in another sheet using a unique identifier found on both sheets.

I have two separate sheets in Excel, `sheet1` contains user information including name, gender and a unique ID that looks more or less like this:

```
      A      | B |  C
John Doe     | M | 112 
Jane Doe     | F | 147 
Kerry West   | F | 293
Robert Smith | M | 861
```

`Sheet 2` contains a unique identifier and a score like this:

```
 A  | B
112 | 15
147 | 12
293 | 18
861 | 11
```

What I want to do is separate the two groups in sheet two based on gender. So basically I would somehow take the unique ID on sheet two, find it in sheet 1 and then check the gender associated with that unique ID so that sheet two would end up looking like this:

```
 A  | B  |  C  | D
112 | 15 | 147 | 12
861 | 11 | 293 | 18
```

So that the rows identified as male are left in their columns while rows identified as female are moved to columns C and D. I just can't figure out how I'm meant to do this and it's driving me nuts. any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Create a sheet named "Sheet3" and that's where the summary will populate. This should get you started.

```
Sub nameList()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim lc1, lc2, x, y, i, vLook

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

lc1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lc2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

x = 2
y = 2
For i = 2 To lc1
    vLook = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sh1.Cells(i, 3), Range(sh2.Cells(1, 1), sh2.Cells(lc2, 2)), 2, "false")
    If sh1.Cells(i, 2) = "M" Then
        sh3.Cells(x, 1) = sh1.Cells(i, 3)
        sh3.Cells(x, 2) = vLook
        x = x + 1
    Else
        sh3.Cells(y, 3) = sh1.Cells(i, 3)
        sh3.Cells(y, 4) = vLook
        y = y + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```